# CROSS APPLY query very slow when additional column added

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `CROSS APPLY` query which executes very quickly (1 second). However, if I add certain additional columns to the top `SELECT`, the query will run very slow (many minutes).  I'm not seeing what is causing this.

```
SELECT 
    cs.show_title, im.primaryTitle
FROM
    captive_state cs 
CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT TOP 1 
         imdb.tconst, imdb.titleType, imdb.primaryTitle,
         imdb.genres, imdb.genre1, imdb.genre2, imdb.genre3
     FROM 
         imdb_data imdb 
     WHERE 
         (imdb.primaryTitle LIKE cs.show_title+'%') 
         AND (imdb.titleType like 'tv%' OR imdb.titleType = 'movie')
     ORDER BY 
         imdb.titleType, imdb.tconst DESC) AS im 
WHERE 
    cs.genre1 IS NULL
```

I've tried adding/removing various columns and only when adding the 'genre' fields - e.g. genre2 (varchar(50)) - does the slowness occur.  For example,

```
SELECT cs.show_title, im.primaryTitle, im.genre2
```

I would expect the query to basically have the same performance whether adding one additional column or not.

Here are the query plans without the extra column, and with.

[image: Est Execution Plan1]

[image: Est Execution Plan2]

The first table (cs) has a primary key index and an index on genre1.  The second table (imdb) has a primary key index and an index on primaryTitle.

I'm not sure if those would cause any problems though.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare. Also include both queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second screenshot, you're performing an Index Scan on the primary key for `imdb_data`.  This is essentially scanning the table as if there is no index.

You have two options.  Either change your query to use the indexed columns of `imdb_data` or create a new index to cover this query.

Comment: Yes you're correct.  If I add an index hint to use the existing primaryTitle index, the query performs very quickly.  For example, in my original query, if I do this:

**
SELECT cs.show_title, im.primaryTitle, im.genre2
:
    FROM imdb_data imdb WITH (INDEX(idx_primaryTitle))
**
the query performs very quickly.  So the optimizer is somehow discarding the index if I wish to return an extra column, unless I force it to use it.  Weird.

Comment: @BeachBum without knowing the details of your index, it's hard to say exactly why.  But a common reason is because the columns you are selecting may not be in the index.  You can always INCLUDE the columns in your query in the index so the query is fully covered by the index.  Anyways, if my answer was helpful would you mind marking it as an answer? Would help me out with that reputation grind! :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe switch to an alternative for the topped CROSS APPLY

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES 
 cs.show_title, 
 imdb.tconst, imdb.titleType, imdb.primaryTitle,
 imdb.genres, imdb.genre1, imdb.genre2, imdb.genre3
FROM captive_state cs 
JOIN imdb_data imdb 
  ON imdb.primaryTitle LIKE cs.show_title+'%'
 AND (imdb.titleType = 'movie' OR imdb.titleType LIKE 'tv%')
WHERE cs.genre1 IS NULL
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cs.show_title ORDER BY imdb.titleType, imdb.tconst DESC)
```

Comment: Yes, this works as an alternative and is a good solution.  However, I'm still not clear why adding an extra column would take the query from 1 second to 10 minutes.

Comment: Mattkwish explained why the second plan is slow. It scans the table. Because those other field are included the query optimizer must have thought that it was faster to both search & retrieve it directly from the table. If the first query only needed the title, the could get that from that index alone.

Comment: @LukStorms you stole my answer! ;) but you're exactly right, the best approach is to utilize the existing index if you can't change it.

Comment: @Mattkwish Yeah, it surprized me too that BeachBum switched that approval to mine.  I hadn't explain in my answer why that plan changed, since you already did anyway.  This question kinda surprized me that the optimizer would do something silly like this.  I mean, that outer query in his SQL doesn't even select those extra fields. Maybe the optimizer is more fine tuned for finding the best plan when using normal joins, compared to using a cross apply or a nested query.

Comment: Sorry about changing the approvals around.  I changed it back to the original (I thought you could approve more than 1).  In any case, yes the optimizer is acting very screwy here and it would be great to get an explanation from the SQL Server (2016) team how this could possibly happen.

Answer (score 0):

You could include additional columns to index `[imdb_data].[idx_primary_table]. (name is not readable from screenshot)`:

[image]

```
CREATE INDEX idx_name ON [imdb_data].[idx_primary_table](same cols as in original)
INCLUDE (genre1, genre2, genre3) WITH (DROP_EXISTING=ON)
```

Comment: Ok, I could do that.  But that's kind of like saying that 
SELECT firstname, lastname FROM mytable
takes 1 second but
SELECT firstname, lastname, middlename FROM mytable
takes 10 minutes, unless I add columns to my index.  To me that doesn't make sense.  In the first query, it is shown that the records are retrieved in 1 second.  Adding one more column shouldn't slow it down by 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "join" with "row_number()" instead of "apply"

```
select
     dat.primaryTitle
    ,dat.show_title
from (
    select
         imdb.primaryTitle
        ,cs.show_title
        ,row_number() over (partition by cs.show_title order by imdb.titleType, imdb.tconst DESC) as rn
    from imdb_data imdb
    inner join captive_state cs on imdb.primaryTitle LIKE cs.show_title+'%'
    where (imdb.titleType like 'tv%' OR imdb.titleType = 'movie')
    and cs.genre1 IS NULL
) dat
where dat.rn = 1
```